# React: How can I import only a specific subset of data from a data file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a long list of financial data stored in a JS File:

```
{
  StockId: 0, 
  link: "/Stock-detail",
  StockName: "Wayne Enterprises",
  StockPrice: "81.58 CHF",
  StockChange: "-3%",
  StockCategory: 'Real Estate'
  StockMarketCap: "909T",
  StockMarketVolume: "853T",
  StockTrend: "pos",
  StockPriceChart: TrendPos,
  StockMinInvest: "500,00 CHF",
  StockRegulators: "FINMA",
```

How can I pass / filter only a specific subset of this data, *for example only those entries with the Stock Category 'Real Estate'*, into a component? This is how data is currently passed:

```
 Stock.map(item => {
                return (
                  <StockTile 
                    StockName={item.StockName}
                    StockType={item.StockType}
                    StockCategory:{item.StockCategory}
                    StockPrice={item.StockPrice}
                    link={item.link}
                    StockTrend={item.StockTrend}
                    StockPriceChart={item.StockPriceChart}
                  />
                )
              })
            }
```

Comment: What format does your data have? In your post, you show a (half) JS object, from your question it sounds like it's an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Stock.filter(item => item.StockCategory === "Real Estate").map(item => {
    return (
        <StockTile
            StockName={item.StockName}
            StockType={item.StockType}
            StockCategory={item.StockCategory}
            StockPrice={item.StockPrice}
            link={item.link}
            StockTrend={item.StockTrend}
            StockPriceChart={item.StockPriceChart}
        />
    );
});
```

Comment: @DennoFreezy, check this out!!

Comment: I was getting blank entries until I've realized you switched '.map'  to .'filter'  - working perfectly now!